# Build a dictionary with the words of a sentence as keys and the number of position of the words from 1 as values in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I expect this output from the code below:

```
{'Tell': 1, 'a': 2, 'little': 3, 'more': 4, 'about': 5, 'yourself': 6, 'as': 7, 'a': 8, 'developer': 9}
```

But I get this output:

```
{'Tell': 1, 'a': 8, 'little': 3, 'more': 4, 'about': 5, 'yourself': 6, 'as': 7, 'developer': 9}
```

This is the code:

```
sentence = 'Tell a little more about yourself as a developer'
list_words = sentence.split()

d = {word: i for i, word in enumerate(list_words, 1)}

print(d)
```

What do you think is the problem? What is the code that gives the output I want?

Comment: You have the word 'a' twice, so the dictionary will only provide word:i for the last pair.  Thus, a dictionary can only be used for this purpose if the words of a sentence are unique.  Would suggest using a list of tuples i.e. `[(word, i) for i, word in enumerate(list_words, 1)]`

Comment: There can only be one value with the key `'a'`. Your code overwrites the original value of the key when `'a'` is encountered a second time. If you want the value for the key to be for the *first* occurrence, you will need to code for that behavior.

Comment: in your code i is the position in the enumerate list, not the count of words. You have to look at this to fix your problem.

Comment: Python dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys. What was the source of this question?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have two identical keys in a dictionary so it is impossible to get your expected result where 'a' is present twice (once for 'a':2 and again for 'a':8).

You output data structure could be a list of tuples instead of a dictionary:

```
r = [(word,i) for i,word in enumerate(list_words,1)]

[('Tell', 1), ('a', 2), ('little', 3), ('more', 4), ('about', 5), 
 ('yourself', 6), ('as', 7), ('a', 8), ('developer', 9)]
```

Or, it could be a dictionary with a list of positions for each word:

```
d = dict()
for i,word in enumerate(list_words,1):
    d.setdefault(word,[]).append(i)

{'Tell': [1], 'a': [2, 8], 'little': [3], 'more': [4], 
 'about': [5], 'yourself': [6], 'as': [7], 'developer': [9]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the Index of the list to get the order of the words in your sentence.

```
sentence = 'Tell a little more about yourself as a developer'
list_words = sentence.split()

words = [(value, index+1) for index, value in enumerate(list_words)]
print(words)

#output 
[('Tell', 1), ('a', 2), ('little', 3), ('more', 4), ('about', 5), ('yourself', 6), ('as', 7), ('a', 8), ('developer', 9)]
```

Your requested output is a dictionary, but in a specific order. Python  dictionaries don't support duplicate keys (a, a), which creates problems with getting this output.

```
sentence = 'Tell a little more about yourself as a developer'
list_words = sentence.split()

words = [(value, index+1) for index, value in enumerate(list_words)]

dict_words = {}
for item in words:
    dict_words.update({item[0]:item[1]})

print(dict_words)

#output
{1: 'Tell', 2: 'a', 3: 'little', 4: 'more', 5: 'about', 6: 'yourself', 7: 'as', 8: 'a', 9: 'developer'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence ='Tell a little more about yourself as a developer'
list_words=sentence.split()
uniquewords = list(set(list_words))
d = {i:0 for i in uniquewords}
for i in list_words:
    for j in s1:
        if i==j:
            d[j]+=1
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you printed the index of the letters instead of the index of the words.

You can try:

```
sentence = 'Tell a little more about yourself as a developer'

words_list = sentence.split()

words_dictionary = dict()

for word in words_list:
    words_dictionary[word] = words_list.index(word) + 1

print(words_dictionary)

#output :
# {'Tell': 1, 'a': 2, 'little': 3, 'more': 4, 'about': 5, 'yourself': 6, 'as': 7, 'developer': 9}
```